# POST JSON from HTML form to PHP API and download the received file in the browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, post

I have an existing API that only accepts JSON values via a POST, it responds with a downloadable zip file that is only session based, not on a server.  I wanted to create an HTML form that could be filled out and POST the JSON values to the API then receive the download.  Once the API receives the JSON it will respond with a Zip file that should be downloaded through the browser.  I spent a lot of time searching for how to do this and eventually pulled together the components to make it happen.  I wanted to share it here because I saw many other people searching for the same thing but with no clear answers or script that worked, lost of GET examples but no POST with in memory server data.  In fact may folks said it just couldn't be done with POST.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (event) {                           
    //Function montiors for the form submit event
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default action of the form submit button
    var jsonData = '{"PONumber":"' + form1.PONumber.value //JSON data being submitted to the API from the HTML form
            + '","CompanyName":"' + form1.CompanyName.value 
            + '","CompanyID":"' + form1.CompanyID.value 
            + '","ProductName":"' + form1.ProductName.value 
            + '","Quantity":"' + form1.quantity.value 
            + '","Manufacturer":"' + form1.Manufacturer.value + '"}';   

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'api_page.php', true); //The POST to the API page where the JSON will be submitted
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');       //Additional header fields as necessary
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciO----< SNIP >---547OWZr9ZMEvZBiQpVvU0K0U');
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'application/zip'});  //We're downloading a Zip file
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = downloadUrl;
            a.download = "download_file.zip"; //The name for the downloaded file that will be saved    
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();                                              //Automatically starts the download
        } else {
            alert('Unable to download file.')
            }
    };

    xhr.send(jsonData);    //Sends the JSON data to the destination POST page

});

});
</script>
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" action="" >
   <td><center><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"></center></td>
   <td ><strong>ENTER QUANTITY OF UNITS:  </strong></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input name="quantity" type="text" size="17" value="<?php echo $row['value'];?>"></td>
</form>
```

Here is the code for the PHP server side of the application.  The first part is to receive the request.

```
//Receive the incoming JSON data from the form POST
$jsonRequest = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

//Attempt to decode the incoming RAW post data.
$requestDecoded = json_decode($jsonRequest, true);

//Do something with the data and then respond with a zip file.
```

Here is the PHP code that sends the Zip file back to the original requesting page for download.

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');  //Creates output buffer
$mfiles = $yourZipFile   
if($fp && $mfiles) {
     header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
     header("Content-Type: application/zip");
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
                  filename=\"".basename($zipName)."\";");
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
     header("Content-Length: " .strlen($mfiles));
     header("Response-Data: ".$responseData);
     ob_end_clean();
     if (fputs($fp, $mfiles, strlen($mfiles))===FALSE){
         throw new Exception($e);
        }
     }
     else { 
         throw new Exception($e); 
     }
```

Comment: It's good that you want to share what you've learned, and self-answers are encouraged, but you should really consider reorganizing this post a bit so that the question is a question and the answer answers it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for the feedback.  This was the first self answer and I didn't even know it was an option till I got to the end.  I'll make sure the next one is better organized.

Answer (score 0):

Place the javascript code in the body of your HTML page and it should work just fine.  I hope this helps someone else out there in the same position.  I've tried to describe each component as best I can and include all of the pieces to make it work.

```
Request:  Browser --> HTML form --> JSON --> POST --> PHP
Response: PHP --> zip file --> Browser Download --> Local PC
```